# How to get a count of unique rows?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a count of rows that only differ by one record so I can find out what is "historically" the correct row by determining the most frequently occurring combination. The rows will look something like this:

```
RowAVal1 | RowAVal2 | RowAVal3 | DiffVal1
RowAVal1 | RowAVal2 | RowAVal3 | DiffVal1
RowAVal1 | RowAVal2 | RowAVal3 | DiffVal2
RowAVal1 | RowAVal2 | RowBVal1 | DiffVal1
```

For this example, for the RowAVal1 | RowAVal2 | RowAVal3 combination, the rows with DiffVal1 would be the historically correct combination because it appears the most. I need to figure out how to count these rows.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Gordon's answer worked pretty well. I wanted each of those columns, plus the count of the fourth column. I'm using Gordon outlined, but instead of specifying seqnum = 1, I'm using seqnum > 1 to pick out the "duplicates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the most common value of the fourth column for combinations of the first three.   This is called the *mode* in statistics and is easy to calculate with aggregation and window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select col1, col2, col3, col4, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, col3 order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by col1, col2, col3, col4
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! The mode isn't exactly what I was wanting but it was very helpful pointing me in the right direction.